# Most efficient way to bind DataRowView[] to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a DataView (with sort columns, and no RowFilter) over a DataTable. When I call `DataView.FindRows(SortCols[])` it returns `DataRowView[]`.

What is the most efficient way (in terms of speed), to bind this array to a DataGridView?

My google searches returned just a couple of relevant results, and they seem to recommend iterating over the array and adding the data to a new DataTable, which could then be bound.

I expect my DataRowView[] to contain at least a few hundred items, so I would not like to go the iteration way unless nothing better is available.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually do following : datagridview1.DataSource = dt;  Or if fileter create new DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Col_A") == "ABC").CopyToDataTable();

Comment: That's no good in my case.

Comment: Using AsEnumerable() is very fast,  You can test the performance.  The slow part is refreshing the DGV control.  You have to be careful to make sure you refresh the DGV only once.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. But my reason for using the DataView is that it is the only way to create an index on multiple columns of the DataTable, and then the FindRows() effectively makes use of the corresponding index. I'd like to stick to that, rather than using Linq. The only difficulty I'm facing is that FindRows returns an array of DataRowView, which cannot be directly bound to a DataGridView, hence this question.

Comment: You can always add a new column to a DataTable and add the index number.  With your way you still have to put the array of rows into a datatable.

Comment: I do not wish to modify my structures midway a project. Too much is dependent on it, and I haven't much time to restructure everything. I'm just looking for an efficient way to put the array of DataRowView into a new DataTable (without having to iterate over the whole lot of columns and rows). I'm sure there must be a way to do this. Surprised nobody has posted anything across the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little trial and error, I ended up with this solution. I do iterate over the array, but could avoid second level iteration over columns:

```
DataRowView[] drvFiltered = NFM.dtvFilterRothAppMsgs.FindRows(new string[] { sSenderCompId, sTargetCompId });

//-- Current solution
DataRow dr;
foreach (DataRowView drv in drvFiltered) {
    dr = dtbFilteredAppMsgs.NewRow();
    dr.ItemArray = drv.Row.ItemArray;
    dtbFilteredAppMsgs.Rows.Add(dr);
}
dtbFilteredAppMsgs.AcceptChanges();
```

It works, for now. If anybody knows of a more direct method, please do let me know. Many thanks.